# Tag merge request: [tests] and [testing]

Tags: discussion, tags

We have two very similar tags:

- [tests](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tests): 16
- [testing](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/testing): 12

My personal preference is to eliminate `[tests]` and stick with `[testing]` (only because `-ing` implies are more active or ongoing sense to me), but I don't care enough to fight hard for it.

Answer (score 3):

### kill `[tests]`

I agree 100%!

Answer (score 0):

### kill `[testing]`

I agree 50%! Right impulse, wrong conclusion.

Answer (score -1):

### No killing

I agree 0%. Leave them be. Or something else...